Неточность при операции с Decimal и дробью в периоде
Я пробую сложить числа наподобие 0,7 и 1/3:
print(Decimal(0.7)+Decimal(1/3))

но при сложении этих чисел выводит 1.033333333333333288924412348. Как это исправить, если я не могу использовать округление, так как планируется проект наподобие калькулятора?

Вы какой результат ожидали?

print(Decimal('0.7')+Decimal(1)/Decimal(3)). В вашем примере все значения испорчены ограниченной точностью double и в Decimal они попадают округлённые.

Дополнительно: Decimal не может хранить произвольные рациональные дроби (как 1/3) без погрешности. Только десятичные дроби. Для рациональных дробей есть fractions.

Кстати, а сколько знаков после запятой ваш калькулятор планирует показывать? Вряд ли так много, а тогда в общем-то погрешности в дальних знаках особого значения и не имеют. Но в целом конечно полезно знать, как это всё работает.

Это неточность не Decimal, а неточность встроенных чисел с плавающей точкой самого Питона, которые вы передаёте в конструктор Decimal, это 0.7 и 1/3, которые уже неточно передаются в Decimal.
Кстати, есть полезный приём, который не даст вам в дальнейшем делать такие ошибки (не даст вам смешивать типыfloat и Decimal):
from decimal import getcontext, FloatOperation, Decimal

c = getcontext()
c.traps[FloatOperation] = True

print(Decimal(0.7)+Decimal(1/3))

Получаем исключение FloatOperation:
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
FloatOperation                            Traceback (most recent call last)
      3 c = getcontext()
      4 c.traps[FloatOperation] = True
----> 5 print(Decimal(0.7)+Decimal(1/3))

FloatOperation: [<class 'decimal.FloatOperation'>]

Меняем на подсказанное в комментариях, чтобы исключить любые операции с встроенными числами с плавающей точкой самого Питона (тут только строки и целые числа, которые мы передаём сразу в конструктор Decimal, так что они не успевают "испортиться"):
print(Decimal('0.7')+Decimal(1)/Decimal(3))

И получаем (с prec по умолчанию 28):
1.033333333333333333333333333


ещё добавлю, что в целом, проблема точности чисел с плав.точкой довольно распространена. Недавно даже нашёл забавный сайт на эту тему https://0.30000000000000004.com/

@Dezmonder Ну да, это известная проблема, ей посвящены статьи, сайты, вопросы на СО... )

Я без предварительных танцев ввёл вот это в консоли: decimal.Decimal('0.7')+decimal.Decimal(1)/decimal.Decimal(3) и получил результат: Decimal('1.033333333333333333333333333')

А можно и так даже: decimal.Decimal('0.7')+decimal.Decimal('1')/decimal.Decimal('3')

@FoxFox Ну это понятно, я просто показал, как избежать подобных граблей в будущем. Не всегда они явно заметны, а тут сразу эксепшен будет, если что не так. А так то с одной стороны передавать всё строками - это универсальное решение, делай всё строками, и не ошибёшься, но всё же несколько избыточное. Целые числа ничем не хуже.
